# Hypothesis testing for k-times-k-fold cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, cross-validation

I've done 10-times-10-fold cv over 4 datasets for 2 different machine learning classification models. So I obtain 100 performance metrics(eg. balanced accuracy) for each dataset.

I would like to statistically test if the difference in performance between models is significant across all datasets.

I would usually do an ANOVA with independent variables: model (2 levels) and dataset (4 levels); dependent variable being the performance metric. But I can already see there is a complication with the process that generates the data, as this cv produces not completely independent (overlapping) measures.

My objective is to prove that 1 model outperforms the other across all datasets.

Any idea of how could I proceed? Also references and resources would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.